# ruby on EC2 install problem with zlib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I read a similar post but I am not using ubuntu, and do not have apt-get.

fyi, uname: x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

When attempting to do "gem install rails", I get

```
[root@domU-12-31-39-07-7D-C1 ruby-1.9.2-p136]# gem install rails
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

However, when I do "yum install zlib", it says that is installed.

```
[root@domU-12-31-39-07-7D-C1 ruby-1.9.2-p136]# yum install zlib
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Package zlib-1.2.3-24.6.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I tryed `which zlib` and have confirmed it doesn't exist. Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! I found an answer here: http://lucaschan.com/weblog/2007/03/22/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-centosredhat-4x/

I only needed a subset of his instructions which was to go into the source and:

```
cd ruby-1.9.2-p136/ext/zlib/
ruby extconf.rb --with-zlib-include=/usr/include --width-zlib-lib=/usr/lib
gem install rails --include-dependencies
```

That's it! Thanks to Lucas;)

Comment: `--width-zlib-lib` should probably be `--with-zlib-lib`. I'm not sure about @Richard's proposed-edit, seems unlikely, but without knowing I'm not keen on editing the post to fix this myself.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem the other day, and my solution was: "switch to REE"... which correctly installed gems

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error through search.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1494997#post11359766

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
cd /ruby-source-files/ext/zlib
#rvm ~/.rvm/src/ruby-*.*.*/ext/zlib
ruby extconf.rb
make
sudo make install
```